# The fundamental theorem of calculus in higher dimension

Tags: real-analysis

We know that the following result holds in $\mathbb{R}$: if $f$ is continuous on every compact of $\mathbb{R}$, then the function $$x\mapsto\int_{a}^{x}f(t)~\mathrm{d}t$$ ($a$ is a fixed real number) is differentiable and its derivative at $x$ is $f(x)$. My question is: Is there such a result in higher dimension? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes, [Stokes's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27s_theorem).

Comment: While Stokes' theorem generalize the 2nd FTC, I don't think there's a generalization of the 1st FTC (the part you're asking about).  If it existed I would imagine it'd have a form something like $\nabla^2 \iint_S f\mathrm{d}S = f(x,y,z)$, but that just isn't true in general.

Comment: Okay.  According to the [wikipedia page on the FTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations) there IS one: the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem).  Cool beans.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the stokes/gauss (or curl/divergence) theorems as the multidimensional equivalent of the fundamental theorem of calculus.
Quoting from Thomas' Calculus:

"*A Unifying Fundamental Theorem*

The integral of a differential operator acting on a field over a region equals the
sum of the field components appropriate to the operator over the boundary of the
region.
"

Comment: That's for $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^2$. There is a more general formulation.